# Apache poi add label in excel chart

Tags: java, excel, charts, apache-poi, label

```
public class LineChart {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try (XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook()) {
            XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("linechart");
            final int NUM_OF_ROWS = 3;
            final int NUM_OF_COLUMNS = 10;

            // Create a row and put some cells in it. Rows are 0 based.
            Row row;
            Cell cell;
            for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < NUM_OF_ROWS; rowIndex++) {
                row = sheet.createRow((short) rowIndex);
                for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < NUM_OF_COLUMNS; colIndex++) {
                    cell = row.createCell((short) colIndex);
                    cell.setCellValue(colIndex * (rowIndex + 1.0));
                }
            }

            XSSFDrawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
            XSSFClientAnchor anchor = drawing.createAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 10, 15);

            XSSFChart chart = drawing.createChart(anchor);
            XDDFChartLegend legend = chart.getOrAddLegend();
            legend.setPosition(LegendPosition.BOTTOM);

            // Use a category axis for the bottom axis.
            XDDFCategoryAxis bottomAxis = chart.createCategoryAxis(AxisPosition.BOTTOM);
            //bottomAxis.setTitle("x"); // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32010765
            XDDFValueAxis leftAxis = chart.createValueAxis(AxisPosition.LEFT);
            //leftAxis.setTitle("f(x)");
            leftAxis.setCrosses(AxisCrosses.AUTO_ZERO);

            XDDFDataSource<Double> xs = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromNumericCellRange(sheet, new CellRangeAddress(0, 0, 0, NUM_OF_COLUMNS - 1));
            XDDFNumericalDataSource<Double> ys1 = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromNumericCellRange(sheet, new CellRangeAddress(1, 1, 0, NUM_OF_COLUMNS - 1));
            XDDFNumericalDataSource<Double> ys2 = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromNumericCellRange(sheet, new CellRangeAddress(2, 2, 0, NUM_OF_COLUMNS - 1));

            XDDFLineChartData data = (XDDFLineChartData) chart.createData(ChartTypes.LINE, bottomAxis, leftAxis);
            XDDFLineChartData.Series series1 = (XDDFLineChartData.Series) data.addSeries(xs, ys1);
            series1.setTitle("2x", null); // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21855842
            series1.setSmooth(false); // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29014848
            series1.setMarkerStyle(MarkerStyle.DOT); // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39636138
            series1.setShowLeaderLines(true);
            XDDFLineChartData.Series series2 = (XDDFLineChartData.Series) data.addSeries(xs, ys2);
            series2.setTitle("3x", null);
            //series2.setSmooth(true);
            //series2.setMarkerSize((short) 6);
            //series2.setMarkerStyle(MarkerStyle.NONE); // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39636138
            series2.setShowLeaderLines(false);

            chart.plot(data);

            // if your series have missing values like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29014848
            // chart.displayBlanksAs(DisplayBlanks.GAP);

            // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24676460
            solidLineSeries(data, 0, PresetColor.CHARTREUSE);
            solidLineSeries(data, 1, PresetColor.BLACK);

            // Write the output to a file
            try (FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("ooxml-line-chart.xlsx")) {
                wb.write(fileOut);
            }
        }
    }
    //CTPresetLineDashProperties
    private static void solidLineSeries(XDDFChartData data, int index, PresetColor color) {
        XDDFSolidFillProperties fill = new XDDFSolidFillProperties(XDDFColor.from(color));
        XDDFLineProperties line = new XDDFLineProperties();
        //line.setPresetDash(new XDDFPresetLineDash(PresetLineDash.DOT));
        line.setFillProperties(fill);
        XDDFChartData.Series series = data.getSeries().get(index);
        XDDFShapeProperties properties = series.getShapeProperties();
        if (properties == null) {
            properties = new XDDFShapeProperties();
        }
        properties.setLineProperties(line);
        series.setShapeProperties(properties);
    }
}
```

This is an example from:
http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/examples/LineChart.java

And I use poi version is 4.1.1.

when I use `series1.setShowLeaderLines(true) or series2.setShowLeaderLines(false)`
it will show label as picture 1, and contains Series Name, Category Name, Value and Legend Key,
also label position is Right.

Is it possible to change it picture 2 which just contain Value and label position is Center?
Thank you

[current view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrV0c.png)   [what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFxIT.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `XDDF` is not complete yet. The `XDDFLineChartData.Series.setShowLeaderLines` sets default data lables if not present.

As of current `Excel` versions default data lables means including value, legend key, category name and series name. So all this is shown.

`XDDFLineChartData.Series` lacks methods for customizing the data labels except of the leader lines. So this needs to be done using the low level `ooxml-schemas` classes and methods.

In your case:

```
...
            series1.setShowLeaderLines(true); // this sets default data lables
            // customizing data labels
            int seriesNr = 0;
            //chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getLineChartArray(0).getSerArray(seriesNr).getDLbls()
            // .addNewSpPr().addNewSolidFill().addNewSrgbClr().setVal(new byte[]{(byte)255,(byte)255,0});
            chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getLineChartArray(0).getSerArray(seriesNr).getDLbls()
             .addNewDLblPos().setVal(org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.STDLblPos.CTR);
            chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getLineChartArray(0).getSerArray(seriesNr).getDLbls().addNewShowVal().setVal(true);
            chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getLineChartArray(0).getSerArray(seriesNr).getDLbls().addNewShowLegendKey().setVal(false);
            chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getLineChartArray(0).getSerArray(seriesNr).getDLbls().addNewShowCatName().setVal(false);
            chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getLineChartArray(0).getSerArray(seriesNr).getDLbls().addNewShowSerName().setVal(false);
...
```