# How to get series labels to show using apache poi when importing into Google Sheets

Tags: java, apache-poi, label, series, linegraph

I am using Apache POI to generate a line graph and import into Google Sheets.  Regardless of what I try, I cannot seem to get series labels to show.

[image: Line graph with missing series labels]

Here is what I tried:

```
XDDFLineChartData.Series
    todoSeries =
        (XDDFLineChartData.Series) data.addSeries(dateDataSource, todoDataSource),
    doneSeries =
        (XDDFLineChartData.Series) data.addSeries(dateDataSource, doneDataSource),
    deltaSeries =
        (XDDFLineChartData.Series) data.addSeries(dateDataSource, deltaDataSource);

todoSeries.setTitle("Todo", null);
todoSeries.setSmooth(true);
todoSeries.setMarkerStyle(MarkerStyle.CIRCLE);


doneSeries.setTitle("Done", new CellReference(countsRowStart-1, 10, true, true));
doneSeries.setSmooth(true);
doneSeries.setMarkerStyle(MarkerStyle.CIRCLE);

deltaSeries.setTitle("Delta", new CellReference(countsRowStart-1, 11, true, true));
deltaSeries.setSmooth(true);
deltaSeries.setMarkerStyle(MarkerStyle.CIRCLE);
```

But none of these appears to work.

Comment: Cannot reproducuíng. For me `setMarkerStyle` works. So to be able to reproduce your issue, we would need [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). There is an example for creating line charts in https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/examples/. This one can take as basis.

Comment: SetMarkerStyle works, but what I am having issues with is setTitle.  For some reason, I cannot get setTitle to work.  I'll look at the example you referenced.

Comment: For me `setTitle` works too. So same requirement. We would need a minimal, reproducible example to reproduce the issue. Have you tried the linked `LineChart.java`example? There `setTitle` also is used and works. So what are you doing different?

Comment: This turned out to be an issue on my side or rather Google Sheets side.  I got a hold of an Excel viewer and it properly shows the graph.  When importing into Google Sheets, the labels are missing.  Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: Please mention in your question that the problem only occurs using `Google Sheets` to make this clear for other readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Apache POI` is made to create `Microsoft Office` files for usage in `Microsoft Office` applications. So if the need is to make the files usable in other than `Microsoft Office` applications, then we need considering the requirements of those applications. Especially `Google Sheets` (but also `Docs` and `Slides`) sometimes is very different in parsing `Microsoft Office` files from `Microsoft Office` itself. Thus it can become very tedious to make `Microsoft Office` files usable for `Google Sheets`, `Docs` and `Slides`.

You have found that the chart series titles are not shown in charts of `Microsoft Office` files. This occurs when the titles were not taken from cells of the chart's data sheet but were be set as literals. So this problem can be solved by putting the series titles into the chart's data sheet and then using [XDDFChartData.Series.setTitle](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xddf/usermodel/chart/XDDFChartData.Series.html#setTitle-java.lang.String-org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellReference-) giving the correct [CellReference](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/util/CellReference.html) instead of `null`. But the `CellReference` must contain the sheet name too.

Example:

Given `sheet` being the chart's data sheet having title of first series in `A2`  and `series1` being a `XDDFChartData.Series`:

```
series1.setTitle("Series 1", new CellReference(sheet.getSheetName(), 1, 0, true, true));
```

Using this, `Google Sheets` will show the series title too.

Complete example based on https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/examples/xssf/usermodel/ -> LineChart.java.

```
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.examples.*;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress;

import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellReference;

import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.PresetColor;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.XDDFColor;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.XDDFLineProperties;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.XDDFShapeProperties;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.XDDFSolidFillProperties;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.AxisCrosses;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.AxisPosition;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.ChartTypes;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.LegendPosition;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.MarkerStyle;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFCategoryAxis;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFChartData;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFChartLegend;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFDataSource;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFDataSourcesFactory;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFLineChartData;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFNumericalDataSource;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFValueAxis;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFChart;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFClientAnchor;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFDrawing;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;


/**
 * Line chart example.
 */
public final class LineChart {
    private LineChart() {}

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try (XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook()) {
            XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("linechart");

            // Create data for the chart
            Object[][] sheetData = new Object[][] {
                new Object[] {"Categories", 1d, 2d, 3d, 4d, 5d, 6d, 7d, 8d, 9d, 10d},
                new Object[] {"Series 1", 0d, 1d, 2d, 3d, 4d, 5d, 6d, 7d, 8d, 9d},
                new Object[] {"Series 2", 0.5d, 2.5d, 4.5d, 6.5d, 8.5d, 10.5d, 12.5d, 14.5d, 16.5d, 18.5d}
            };

            // Put data for the chart into the sheet
            Row row;
            Cell cell;
            int rowIndex = 0;
            for (Object[] rowData : sheetData) {
                row = sheet.createRow(rowIndex++);
                int colIndex = 0;
                for (Object cellData : rowData) {
                    cell = row.createCell(colIndex++);
                    if (cellData instanceof String) {
                        cell.setCellValue((String)cellData);
                    } else if (cellData instanceof Double) {
                        cell.setCellValue((Double)cellData);
                   }
                }
            }

            XSSFDrawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
            XSSFClientAnchor anchor = drawing.createAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 10, 15);

            XSSFChart chart = drawing.createChart(anchor);
            XDDFChartLegend legend = chart.getOrAddLegend();
            legend.setPosition(LegendPosition.TOP_RIGHT);

            // Use a category axis for the bottom axis.
            XDDFCategoryAxis bottomAxis = chart.createCategoryAxis(AxisPosition.BOTTOM);
            bottomAxis.setTitle("x"); // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32010765
            XDDFValueAxis leftAxis = chart.createValueAxis(AxisPosition.LEFT);
            leftAxis.setTitle("f(x)");
            leftAxis.setCrosses(AxisCrosses.AUTO_ZERO);

            XDDFDataSource<Double> xs = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromNumericCellRange(sheet, new CellRangeAddress(0, 0, 1, 10));
            XDDFNumericalDataSource<Double> ys1 = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromNumericCellRange(sheet, new CellRangeAddress(1, 1, 1, 10));
            XDDFNumericalDataSource<Double> ys2 = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromNumericCellRange(sheet, new CellRangeAddress(2, 2, 1, 10));

            XDDFLineChartData data = (XDDFLineChartData) chart.createData(ChartTypes.LINE, bottomAxis, leftAxis);
            XDDFLineChartData.Series series1 = (XDDFLineChartData.Series) data.addSeries(xs, ys1);

            //series1.setTitle("2x", null); // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21855842
            series1.setTitle("Series 1", new CellReference(sheet.getSheetName(), 1, 0, true, true));

            series1.setSmooth(false); // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29014848
            series1.setMarkerStyle(MarkerStyle.CIRCLE); // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39636138
            series1.setMarkerSize((short) 10);
            XDDFLineChartData.Series series2 = (XDDFLineChartData.Series) data.addSeries(xs, ys2);

            //series2.setTitle("3x", null);
            series2.setTitle("Series 2", new CellReference(sheet.getSheetName(), 2, 0, true, true));

            series2.setSmooth(true);
            series2.setMarkerStyle(MarkerStyle.CIRCLE); // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39636138
            series2.setMarkerSize((short) 10);
            chart.plot(data);

            // if your series have missing values like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29014848
            // chart.displayBlanksAs(DisplayBlanks.GAP);

            // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24676460
            solidLineSeries(series1, PresetColor.CHARTREUSE);
            solidLineSeries(series2, PresetColor.TURQUOISE);

            // Write the output to a file
            try (FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("ooxml-line-chart.xlsx")) {
                wb.write(fileOut);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void solidLineSeries(XDDFChartData.Series series, PresetColor color) {
        XDDFSolidFillProperties fill = new XDDFSolidFillProperties(XDDFColor.from(color));
        XDDFLineProperties line = new XDDFLineProperties();
        line.setFillProperties(fill);
        //XDDFChartData.Series series = data.getSeries().get(index);
        XDDFShapeProperties properties = series.getShapeProperties();
        if (properties == null) {
            properties = new XDDFShapeProperties();
        }
        properties.setLineProperties(line);
        series.setShapeProperties(properties);
    }
}
```

But there are other problems with `Google Sheets` too. For example making markers and axes visible. As said, it can become very tedious to make `Microsoft Office` files usable for `Google Sheets`, `Docs` and `Slides`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It's also important to re-emphasize that `sheet.getSheetName()` must be present to make this work, so the full CellReference constructor must be used. For anyone that's trying to import POI generated output into Google Sheets, using `chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getValAxArray(0).addNewMajorGridlines()` after `chart.plot(data)` will also show "some" gridlines, but it's not perfect. In general, I had limited success in importing Excel Charts into Google Sheets. As Axel mentions, there are multiple problems.