# Apache POI Charting with Dates

Tags: java, excel, graph, apache-poi

I have started working with Apache POI to create an Excel sheet that contains a chart.  The chart is using data that is pretty simple, a date column and a numerical value column.  I want to display the data in date reverse order so the newest data is at the top row in the spreadsheet, but I would like the chart to show the data in date normal order, because I'm also including a trend line, and the direction of the trend line is completely dependent on the ordering of the data.  The date is being displayed on the x-axis, with the y-axis containing the numerical values.  What I want to do is basically reverse all of the data on the chart.  Is there some way to do this?  In Google Sheets, it happens automatically, but that is not an option.
Here's the code I'm currently experimenting with:

```
public void addChart() {
    final int NUM_OF_ROWS = ytd.size();
    final int NUM_OF_COLUMNS = 2;

    // Create a row and put some cells in it. Rows are 0 based.
    XSSFRow row;
    XSSFCell cell;
    List<String> dates = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Double> values = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < NUM_OF_ROWS; rowIndex++) {
        row = (XSSFRow)sheet.createRow((short) rowIndex);
        row.createCell(0).setCellValue(ytd.get(rowIndex).getShipDate());
        dates.add(ytd.get(rowIndex).getShipDate());
        for (int colIndex = 1; colIndex < NUM_OF_COLUMNS; colIndex++) {
            cell = row.createCell((short) colIndex);
            cell.setCellValue(new BigDecimal(ytd.get(rowIndex).getSquareFeet().replaceAll("[,]", "")).doubleValue());
            values.add(new BigDecimal(ytd.get(rowIndex).getSquareFeet().replaceAll("[,]", "")).doubleValue());
        }
    }
    Collections.reverse(dates);
    Collections.reverse(values);
    for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < NUM_OF_ROWS; rowIndex++) {
        row = sheet.getRow((short) rowIndex);
        row.createCell(2).setCellValue(dates.get(rowIndex));
        for (int colIndex = 3; colIndex < 4; colIndex++) {
            cell = row.createCell((short) colIndex);
            cell.setCellValue(values.get(rowIndex));
        }
    }


    XSSFDrawing drawing = (XSSFDrawing) sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
    XSSFClientAnchor anchor = drawing.createAnchor(5, 5, 20, 20, 4, 4, 20, 25);

    XSSFChart chart = drawing.createChart(anchor);
    CTChart ctChart = ((XSSFChart) chart).getCTChart();
//        XSSFChart chart = drawing.createChart(anchor);
    XDDFChartLegend legend = chart.getOrAddLegend();
    legend.setPosition(LegendPosition.TOP_RIGHT);

    // Use a category axis for the bottom axis.
    XDDFDateAxis bottomAxis = chart.createDateAxis(AxisPosition.BOTTOM);
    bottomAxis.setTitle("Ship Date"); // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32010765
    XDDFValueAxis leftAxis = chart.createValueAxis(AxisPosition.LEFT);
    leftAxis.setTitle("Square Feet");
    leftAxis.setCrosses(AxisCrosses.AUTO_ZERO);

    XDDFDataSource<Double> xs = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromNumericCellRange(sheet, new CellRangeAddress(0,  NUM_OF_ROWS - 1, 2, 2));
    XDDFNumericalDataSource<Double> ys1 = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromNumericCellRange(sheet, new CellRangeAddress(0, NUM_OF_ROWS-1, 3, 3));

    XDDFLineChartData data = (XDDFLineChartData) chart.createData(ChartTypes.LINE, bottomAxis, leftAxis);
    XDDFLineChartData.Series series1 = (XDDFLineChartData.Series) data.addSeries(xs, ys1);
    series1.setTitle("SqFt", null); // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21855842
    series1.setSmooth(false); // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29014848
    series1.setMarkerStyle(MarkerStyle.DOT); // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39636138
    chart.plot(data);
//        sheet.setColumnHidden(2, true);
//        sheet.setColumnHidden(3, true);

    // if your series have missing values like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29014848
    // chart.displayBlanksAs(DisplayBlanks.GAP);
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24676460
    solidLineSeries(data, 0, PresetColor.CHARTREUSE);
//        solidLineSeries(data, 1, PresetColor.TURQUOISE);
    chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getLineChartArray(0).getSerArray(0)
            .addNewTrendline()
            .addNewTrendlineType()
            .setVal(org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.STTrendlineType.LINEAR);

    // Write the output to a file
    try (FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("ooxml-line-chart.xlsx")) {
        workbook.write(fileOut);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Exceptions.printStackTrace(ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Exceptions.printStackTrace(ex);
    }
}
```

I've tried putting the data in columns that are hidden, which works fine in LibreOffice, but doesn't work in excel until I un-hide the columns.  So does anyone know if there is a way to control the ordering of the graph data, separate from the data in the table?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution: you can change the direction of the data by modifying the category axis on the chart, using the enum AxisOrientation.  A side effect of getting the data to chart in the order I want, is that the labels for the y-axis now appear on the right instead of the left, but I think I can live with that.